# Instrument with Positive and Negative Affect

Tags: psychometrics, psychology

I am planning to use an instrument "GEQ" that contains 16 items, 4 items are grouped into the following categories:
a. Positive Affect
b. Negative Affect
c. Flow
d. Challenge

scale:
1: strongly agree; 2: Agree; 3:Moderately Agree; 4: Slightly Disagree; 5:Do not agree.

My question is whether we need to reverse the coding-scale for "Negative Affect" during data analysis. I plan to combine and average all the response-data of the four categories (dependent var).

Thanks

Comment: Effect, not affect. If it has a positive effect, it may affect it positively.

Comment: "Positive Affect" is  positive emotion while "Negative Affect" is negative emotions. The wording is correct. My question is whether the scale needs to be reversed during analysis in case of "Negative Affect"